# Login user right inside AWS User Pool

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am facing a lack of service in userpool, I am currently keeping only phone number & MFA / OTP for authentication but on successful signup, I want user to sign in automatically.

In current process user has to multi factor authenticate himself for logging in and registering as well, so it would be unpleasant for user to type OTP code twice, first time for registration and second time right after successful registration for logging in. I get `CognitoUser user` object on successful sign up but I am not sure how can I use it to sign in from application's `UserPool` object. This object stays for listener and there is no way I could find where I can login user using access token, refresh token & ID token received from successful signup listener.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bypass the 2-step SignUp process for your users, you can use the `autoConfirmuser` feature. You can configure a [PreSignUp trigger](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools-working-with-aws-lambda-triggers.html#cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-syntax-pre-signup) which auto confirms every user.

On successful SignUp, your app already has the user's username and password which you can use to authenticate the user without any new user interaction. If you have MFA configured on user pool, the user will be prompted here for the MFA code.